# GDALRasterizeGeometries doesn't burn correct Values

Tags: gdal, c++

What I have is a vector shapefile with a string field. What I've done is written a CSV file with the field `ID, field_value` and now I would like to rasterize the vector layer as a byte raster with the raster pixel value corresponding to the field ID.

I'm not sure what's going wrong but I get a blank raster every single time.

Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```cpp
OGRFeature * ogrFeat;
std::vector<OGRGeometryH> ogrBurnGeometries;
std::vector<double> dBurnValues;

OGRGeometryH hPolygon;

// Create a list of burn-in values
poLayer->ResetReading();
while( (ogrFeat = poLayer->GetNextFeature() ) != NULL ){

    OGRGeometry * ogrGeom;
    // No geometry found. Move along.
    if( ogrFeat->GetGeometryRef() == NULL )
    {
        delete ogrFeat;
        continue;
    }
    ogrGeom = ogrFeat->GetGeometryRef();
    ogrBurnGeometries.push_back( (OGRGeometryH) ogrGeom->clone() );

    if (fieldType == OFTString){
        dBurnValues.push_back( ogrFeat->GetFID() );
    }
    else {
        dBurnValues.push_back( ogrFeat->GetFieldAsDouble(psFieldName) );
    }
    delete ogrFeat;
}
int band = 1;
char **papszRasterizeOptions = NULL;
papszRasterizeOptions =
    CSLSetNameValue( papszRasterizeOptions, "ALL_TOUCHED", "TRUE" );

CPLErr err = GDALRasterizeGeometries( pDSOutput, 1, &band,
                                      1,
                                      &(ogrBurnGeometries[0]),
                                      NULL, NULL,
                                      &(dBurnValues[0]),
                                      NULL,
                                      NULL, NULL );
ogrBurnGeometries.clear();
dBurnValues.clear();
```

**EDIT:** I've fixed a memory problem as suggested by Kyle in the comments. I'm now getting an empty raster with the right extents but the geometries are still not being written.

The CPLErr is empty and the `ogrBurnGeometries` and `dBurnValues` each contain the right values. I am confused.

Comment: Does pDSOutput exist and is it open for read/write? What value do you get for err?

Comment: pDSOutput is open. I am using it the same way I do for my other tools. err doesn't give me anything. The code simply stops executing at the GDALRasterizeGeometries line. Very strange.

Comment: OGRGeometry->GetGeometryRef() returns an internal pointer to the geometry.  When you destroy the feature, the geometry is invalid.  I don't know if that is your issue, but I know it's a problem.  Try copying the geometry, and pushing the copy on to the vector. I think OGR_G_Clone should suffice.

Comment: Yes, it appears that you're deleting the ogrFeat (which cleans up the geometry) before you are attempting to rasterize it, therefore your pointer is to an empty object. Try deleting the ogrFeat *after* the rasterize geometries call.

Comment: huh. I can't believe I missed that. I put in a `clone()` call: `hPolygon = (OGRGeometryH) ogrGeom->clone();` and that solves THAT problem. I think that does it for now. Thanks!